# What are the technologies used to create Metal Gear game?

Tags: software-engineering

What are the technologies (programming languages and engines for example) used to create "Metal Gear : Snake Eater" and "Metal Gear : Guns of The Patriots"?

Is it usual to keep those things secret?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how a particular game was developed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Metal Gear : Guns of The Patriots, [Kojima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kojima_Productions) used their own in-house engine. Its unavailable to general public. C++ is the de-facto of the console game industry. So, I believe it was in this case too.

Recently they are developing a new engine which they have revealed E3 of this year, named [Fox Engine](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/06/02/kojima-announces-multiplatform-fox-engine-powering-upcoming-p/). They say they will be using this multi-platform engine for their future titles.

Answer (score 2):

Each time I see a new Final Fantasy or a MGS game I ask myself the same question. It's obviously the same models, animations, shaders, particle systems and whatnot, but in the hands of certain developers they feel like something out of this world.

I'm quite sure it's was not the bare technologies that made those games, but an amazing art itself, design direction and overall producing. You may find:

- [this forum post](http://mgsforums.com/topic/7131309/1/) an interesting read,
- and watch [these videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvMZ8Lw479s) later.

As you can find out by following the links above, it's nothing totally special or absolutely unknown, but MGS staff turned usual high-tech into a great experience by a burning intent to make an amazing game, also by pouring millions into their art and coding departments :)

Comment: While we're at it, this PDF describes tech used in the making of the "Shadow of the Colossus": www.ninjadodo.net/temp/making_of_sotc.pdf

Comment: Read the shadow of colossus thing awhile back. It was awesome +1